Old movie probably sci-fi - Automated factory
I am giving as many details as I can remember. The movie is quite old (probably 70s-80s). One person (might have been a factory manager) was extremely proud of the automation of the production.
I cannot remember what was produced and I don't think it was important anyway. I only remember the how. A mechanical arm was used. This arm was holding an item which was to be given to another arm (or fitted inside some hole - not sure which). This arm was moving in a very tedious way with lots of rotations and translations. The movement was accompanied by some sort of sound (a bit like the sound of the tanks moving in Total Commander). This scene was shown/in the background many times throughout the movie.
The one scene I remember most was at the end of the movie: the manager looked at the automated process for some time (while the credits ran) and then grabbed the item from the arm and placed it where it belonged with the words, "we don't have time for that now!"
It could have been a Mel Brooks movie, but the titles from Wikipedia did not ring a bell.
The manager was middle aged, and was showing the factory to some other person.
I saw the movie in German, but I suppose it was American or maybe British.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

@Paulie_D: Thanks. I added some details. I am not too sure though.

Reminiscent of Sleeper (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070707/) from 1973, but it's been so long since I've seen it, I can't be sure.

@aryxus: thanks. I'll have a look later. In the worst case, I will have watched a good movie. In the best it is the answer :)

Innerspace (1987), maybe?
I remember they use a robotic arm to complete a process. The movie is in YouTube. Check it out


I finally got to watch it. Yes, it is exactly that movie I was looking for! Thanks!
